# How to determine $Hom (M,M)$ for an irreducible $R$-module $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

More exactly, I'm considering $R$ to be a finite dimensional $\mathbb C$-algebra. For any $R$-module $M$, the $\mathbb C$ vector space $Hom_R(M,M)$ contains scalar multiplication and hence contains the whole of $\mathbb C$. What I want to show that is that if $M$ is irreducible as an $R$-module, then $Hom_R(M,M)=\mathbb C$. I've tried considering any such endomorphism as a map of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces. What next? I think I'll have to look at the eigenspace of any such map, but I don't know hoe to go from there. Can someone give a complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

First note that an irreducible module is always cyclic, hence finite-dimensional if your underlying algebra is finite-dimensional. Now the trick, as you already guessed, is to consider a non-zero eigenspace of your endomorphism and show that it is in fact a submodule.

Comment: How? I can't quite figure out the details. I've tried considering the eigenspace, but why is it a submodule? And what after that?

Comment: I don't want to say more because it's purely a matter of applying definitions which is what you should do yourself in order to learn from the exercise.

Comment: Got it, thanks!